# The body might complete normally, causing 'null' to be returned, but the return type, 'FutureOr<UserModel> and can't be assigned to type 'Uri'

Tags: flutter, authentication, service

I am getting two errors in the below code.

The body might complete normally, causing 'null' to be returned, but the return type, 'FutureOr', is a potentially non-nullable type.
Try adding either a return or a throw statement at the end.

The argument type 'String' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Uri'.

```dart
import 'dart:convert';

import 'package:altamazee/models/user_model.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

class AuthService {
  String baseUrl = 'https://shamo-backend.buildwithangga.id/api';

  Future<UserModel> register({
    required String name,
    required String username,
    required String email,
    required String password,
  }) async {
    var url = '$baseUrl/register';
    var headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/json'};
    var body = jsonEncode({
      'name': name,
      'username': username,
      'email': email,
      'password': password,
    });

    var response = await http.post(
      url,
      headers: headers,
      body: body,
    );

    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      var data = jsonDecode(response.body)['data'];
      UserModel user = UserModel.fromJson(data['user']);
      user.token = 'Bearer ' + data['access_token'];

      return user;
    }
  }
}
```

The first error occurs on the line `Future<UserModel> register({`. The second error is on the line with `http.post`.

Answer (score 0):

The first error is because you don't return anything if your http.post request isn't successful. You can fix this by returning something even if the post request fails, such as using `Future<UserModel?>` as the return type (null if no UserModel is returned), by returning an empty UserModel, or by throwing an error.

The second error is because the first parameter for http.post is a `Uri`, not a string. Build your `Uri` according to the example here: [http package example](https://pub.dev/packages/http/example).

```dart
final url = Uri.https('https://shamo-backend.buildwithangga.id', '/api/register');
```

Answer (score 0):

**First error** says what if you haven’t get any response due to error!

You only checked for 200 status code. If error happens then this block
`if(response.statusCode == 200)` will not be executed.
So, there is nothing to return! You may write like this,

```dart
if(response.statusCode == 200)
{
  // your code 
}
return null; //this will execute if error occurs
```

But doing this will show an error because your return type is, `Future<UserModel>`.
So, change it to `Future<UserModel?>` will fix the first error!

**Second Error**
This worked previously, but now http needs **Uri** type instead of **String**.

Doing like this will fix your error,

```dart
var response = await http.post(
      Uri.parse(url),
      headers: headers,
      body: body,
    );
```